# Laravel: Handling unchecked checkbox with old()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

When I uncheck a checkbox and validation fails I expect that checkbox remains unchecked, instead it is checked.

My checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="member"
  {{ ($mode == 'edit' && $user->member == 1) ? 'checked' : '' }}
  {{ (old('member') == 'on') ? 'checked' : '' }} />
```

Where `$mode == 'edit'` is passed from controller to indentify the case when I'm editing the form and then to populate form fields.

It seems that when checkbox is unchecked the relative `old()` doesn't exist.

I tried a lot of solutions here on Stack but none works. Notice: I'm using Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it by testing the existence of `old('_token')` (the CSRF token) as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="member" 
@if ((!old('_token') &&  $mode == 'edit' && $user->member == 1) || (old('member') == 'on'))
  checked
@endif />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="member" {{ (($mode == 'edit' && $user->member == 1) || old('member')) ? 'checked' : null }} />
```

Comment: Hi Jeune, tried but it doesn't work but maybe it could be for another thing. Please check the updated code in my first post.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work yet. It seems that when checkbox is **un**checked the relative `old()` doesn't exist.